# how to handle firefox download popup in selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

Code:

```
case "firefox":
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "Downloads");  // folder
            profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip");  // MIME type
            profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);  // disable the built-in viewer
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.panel.shown", false);

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, 1);

            webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
            break;
```

Windows popup which i am getting is:[image]

can anyone help me out with this issue??

Comment: Could you try  options.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", false); or  options.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true); and try

Comment: you can use sikuli (image based automation ) to handle this kind op popups

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one line for your setup:
`profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);`

Also I would check if the `browser.download.dir` is not missing proper path to disk (plain"Downloads" might not be enough and you should use full path to disk).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my nightwatch.json file

```
"firefox": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "Firefox",
          'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            prefs: {
              'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk': 'image/jpeg;application/binary;application/pdf;text/plain;application/text;text/xml;application/xml;text/html;text/csv;video/mp4'
            },
          }
        
      }
    }
```

and it helped, although I am still looking if someone can help me out with s similar config for safari